# ¿Cómo sumar totales de venta del dia actual en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera obtener el total de ventas de el día actual en mi consulta de mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esas son las columnas de mi tabla

Comment: ¿y tu consulta y el error que te da?  La pregunta es incompleta para ser válida. Debes mostrar lo que has investigado y decirnos donde te has encallado. La comunidad no está para servirte, sino para ayudarte cuando te encallas, y en este caso no has intentado nada, tan solo has puesto un planteamiento sin ningún intento por tu parte. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo como así:

```
SELECT SUM(ventas.total)
FROM ventas
WHERE DAY(ventas.fecha) = DAY(CURRENT_DATE());
```

Fíjate si eso es lo que querías

Comment: me funciono excelente, gracias